# reportlab - cannot set top margin to zero in physically printed page

Tags: python, layout, reportlab

I am using reportlab 3.0 to generate payment forms where location of each item is strictly defined. I have a problem with reportlab making mandatory topMargin even if I have set topMargin = 0. I can tune bottom margin, but top margin(or area where I cannot print) is about 12 mm, if it is set in code to zero. If I set top margin negative, texts starts dissappearing. I would like to know, what I am missing.  I would have posted the image, but being posted a few posts, I am not able to do it. I have this problem with using SimpleDocTemplate, just using canvas or making the document from BaseDocTemplate. My latest attempt to make top margin correct:

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.platypus import BaseDocTemplate,PageTemplate, Frame
doc = BaseDocTemplate("pdf_file",showBoundary=1,leftMargin=0, rightMargin=0, topMargin=0, bottomMargin=0, pagesize=A4)
frameT = Frame(self.doc.leftMargin, self.doc.bottomMargin, self.doc.width, self.doc.height,    topPadding=0, id='normal')
time = Paragraph('16:37',self.styles["normal"])
doc.build([time])
```

The thing gets interesting as I am able to set bottom margin to zero and print to the border, but in the Top there is non-printable area that is really causing trouble

**Update:** 
After testing this with several printers, I noticed that printer drivers force margins based on their own criteria. For instance, for HP deskjet there was large margin on top. With playing scale settings, it is possible to to tune up somewhat margins, but not too well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it is print drivers...I have a report and i changed my TopMargin from 0.4 * inch to 0.0 * inch and it was lining up right at the top.

```
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, Table, TableStyle, Preformatted, XPreformatted
from reportlab.rl_config import defaultPageSize
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

PAGE_HEIGHT = defaultPageSize[1]; PAGE_WIDTH = defaultPageSize[0]
BottomMargin = 0.4 * inch
TopMargin = 0.4 * inch
LeftMargin = .1 * inch  
RightMargin = .1 * inch
ContentBottomMargin = TopMargin + 0.25 * inch
ContentTopMargin = BottomMargin + 0.35 * inch
ContentLeftMargin = LeftMargin 
ContentRightMargin = RightMargin
```

As you can see these are my regular defaults but I changed TopMargin = 0.0 * inch and it worked.

Maybe it is the difference between me importing defaultPageSize[1] for PAGE_HEIGHT and your importing A4 for page size?

Comment: I have been testing this now, as I got the idea, and it seems that your assumption of printer drivers is correct. Printing pdf from Mac drivers for HP inkjet results a large top margin, while printing from Windows 7 results in expected margin.